# Web user expectations

Tags: user-interface

**When designing a good Web GUI what expectations can we expect from an end user?**

I've come up with the following, but I wonder if there are any others which can suggest..

- If I click on a hyperlink it will take me to another page/part of this page
- If I tick/untick a checkbox it might alter the page state (enable/disable elements)
- If I click on a button I expect it to do something to data.
- If I click on a button I expect something to happen immediately (either to the current page, or for me to be taken to another page)
- If I have clicked on a hyperlink and it has taken me to another page, I expect to be able to use the Back button to get back to the previous page in a state similar to that which I left it in
- If I change something in a form, I can change it back to its previous value if necessary
- Unless I click on the 'Submit' button nothing should happen to my data.
- If I bookmark/favourite a page then it should show the same related data each time I visit it
- If text is underlined and looks like a link, it should be a link and act as one

The reasoning behind this question is more a 'UI from hell' one. For example I have come across pages which checking a tickbox next to a record will delete it, straight away, via ajax. To me that just seems wrong, a checkbox is a toggle - something which a delete operation definitely isn't!

Comment: good question, suggest it gets wiki'd

Comment: it would be better to ask an end user; we are not the users

Comment: @Steven: oh really? You don't use the web at all eh?

Comment: @[annakata]: no, i read html directly and manually write postbacks.

Comment: @Steven it's much faster that way because all you need is the keyboard. Graphical tools are so cumbersome.

Answer (score 7):

- If some text is underlined it shall be a link.
- If I press the back button I shall go back to the previous page, which I will recognise as the previous page.
- If something is happening aysnchronously it shall be obvious to me that it is in flight, and obvious when and in what state it completes.
- If I want to expand or shrink the text size (ctrl++, ctrl+-) it shall not be at the expense of the layout.
- I shall not be presented with a set of radio inputs where I wish to select more than one item.
- If I want to disable Javascript or Flash I shall be allowed to do so, and still have access to the basic features of the site.

Comment: Last one is very true, however a lot of developers ignore these people.

Answer (score 6):

- If a form doesn't validate, I don't expect to have to retype it before trying again
- If a control is disabled, it should be greyed out / denoted in some way
- When I press back I expect to go back, not get thrown out of the system (bloody banking websites)

Comment: +1 for not refilling forms, and I'd go +2 if I could for the disabled grey

Comment: (although sometimes the better solution is not to display a disabled control at all)

Answer (score 2):

There are fundamental principles of UI design embedded in this question.  I strongly recommend everyone who touches on UI design should read, at a minimum, our very own Joel's ["Controlling Your Environment Makes You Happy"](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/chapters/fog0000000057.html), an article that I read some years ago that has stuck with me and is still as relevant today as it was the day it was written.

I also recommend the book ["Don't Make Me Think!"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321344758) as an excellent resource on the principles of good UI design, particularly on the power and importance of convention.

Your list is all about conventions.

Several comments:

- The Back button has always been (and will probably always be as long as the Web exists) controversial.  There are security and usability reasons to disable it's use.  Double-submit might be an annoyance on a forum but it can be a costly error with an order to buy shares.  This can be handled with other techniques (eg POST+REDIRECT+GET or overwriting the browser history) but the point remains: Back button behaviour is not always desirable let alone required;
- Bookmarking a page and expecting the results has some merit (eg if I bookmark a quote for GOOG then I should go back there and get a current quote, not the quote I saw at the time I bookmarked, obviously) but a page result can also be costly so this may not always be appropriate.

I'll add a couple:

- If I can click on it and it's not a button then the cursor should change to a hand when my mouse is over it;
- Conversely, if the cursor changes to a hand, I shold be able to click on it and it'll do something; and
- If there's a box containing some text that has a border and it looks like a text element on a form, then I should be able to type in it unless it indicates that it is "read-only" or "disabled" (eg by greying it out).

Comment: I agree that there are times where back button / reposting is unwanted but most sites fudge the handling of it. Banking sites are notorious in that they kick you out for using back, even when nothing was submitted.

Comment: True but sometimes I think that is unintended consequences.  Like some manager decides no pages should be cached for security.  The result of this can be clicking back resubmits the page.

Comment: I have the 'Don't Make me Think!' book on order already - I'm glad its been recomended!

Answer (score 0):

If an ad says i've won a million dollars, give me the money. If not, make the ad go away.